# How to optionally handle non-zero exit codes when `set -e`

Tags: linux, bash

In script I have set

```
set -e
```

then I run command in if statement in said script:

```
if adb -s emulator-5554 uninstall my.package ; then
    echo "handle emulator command return code here ... "
fi
```

I want to get the return code of command `emulator-5554 uninstall my.package`, and handle the return code depending on its value; I am not able to do this because the command is embedded inside the if statement.

Comment: Reviewing the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) is generally a good use of your time, to set expectations around `set -e`s propensity for unwanted side effects. (https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ is another useful resource, showing how different shells *and different versions of the same shell* behave differently with `set -e` enabled; I'd argue that enabling that flag, as opposed to writing explicit error handling code, does substantial harm to predictability and portability of your scripts).

Comment: Being embedded in an if statement makes it *easier* for you to handle the return code, especially when `set -e` is enabled!

Comment: If `set -e` is enabled (more precisely, if the errexit option is enabled) and your command is *not* in an if statement (and some other caveats), then you can't handle non-zero return codes at all because the script will terminate.  Since it is in an `if` statement, errexit is irrelevant, and the `if` statement filters one of the return codes for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being in an `if` statement does not affect how you get return codes, and `set -e` does not apply to conditional commands:

```
if adb -s emulator-5554 uninstall my.package ; then
    echo "The command succeeded, yay!"
else
    code="$?"
    echo "The command failed with exit code $code"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Another popular mnemonic is `&& ret=0 || ret=$?` or similar. Because assignment `ret=$?` returns zero exit status, the expression exits with zero status. Yet another popular mnemonic is `ret=0; <the command> || ret=$?`

```
adb -s emulator-5554 uninstall my.package && ret=$? || ret=$?

if ((ret == 0)); then
   echo "Yay, success!"
elif ((ret == 1)); then
   echo "Yay, it failed!"
elif ((ret == 2)); then
   echo "Abandon ship!"
else 
   echo "Unhandled error"
fi
```

Be sure not to write it as `|| ret=$? && ret=$?`!

Comment: This is a nice solution, thank you for providing it.